# Postgresql JDBC connection via eclipse not happening

Tags: java, eclipse, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to do a simple connection test to a postgresql database, the code is working well  but I am getting the following message:

*PostgreSQL 9.0 JDBC4 (build 802)
Found in: jar:file:/C:/thales/Dropbox/study/java/jars/postgresql-9.0-802.jdbc4.jar!/org/postgresql/Driver.class*

I am using the jdbc file provided by the address http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html

Following, the code:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class connector {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
  System.out.println("Checking if Driver is registered with DriverManager.");

  try {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
    System.out.println("Couldn't find the driver!");
    System.out.println("Let's print a stack trace, and exit.");
    cnfe.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);
  }

  System.out.println("Registered the driver ok, so let's make a connection.");

  Connection c = null;

  try {
    // The second and third arguments are the username and password,
    // respectively. They should be whatever is necessary to connect
    // to the database.
    c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localserver/test","ping", "pong");
  } catch (SQLException se) {
    System.out.println("Couldn't connect: print out a stack trace and exit.");
    se.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);
  }

  if (c != null)
    System.out.println("Hooray! We connected to the database!");
  else
    System.out.println("We should never get here.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question is confusing.  You're saying that it's showing that message... but according to the message that you gave us, it's just saying that it found the JDBC driver... which isn't a problem...

Comment: Well, i was expecting any output given by any System.out.println and im not sure what could be wrong.

Comment: Have you tried breakpoints in an IDE?  Perhaps you have a connection to your database that is taking a significant amount of time for some reason etc...

Comment: Not that either, im trying under a local database, even with invalid/valid user,pass,host, i still getting the same result described at the post.

Comment: Show full output of your program's execution, and the command line with which you invoked it (eg `java -classpath .... -jar .....`). This looks like a simple misconfiguration issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all feedback but i manage to solve the problem reinstallign eclipse (?? )

using the same code, and the same jdbc driver, the code described in the question worked.